# Retrieving HTML from MongoDB for use in Template

Tags: mongodb, meteor, handlebars.js

I'm new to Meteor.js and MongoDB so this question might have an obvious solution that I am missing but so far my searches have turned up nothing.

My first Meteor project is a very bare-bones blog.  In the MongoDB I have the following:

```
    Blog.insert({
      author: "Name Here",
      title: "Title Here",
      headerHTML: "This is my <b>very</b> first blog post.",
      bodyHTML: "What drives us to <em>solve</em> these types of problems?",
      date: new Date()
    });
```

Then in blog.js I have:

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) {
        Meteor.subscribe("blog");
        Template.posts.entry = function () {
          return Blog.find({});
        };
    }
```

And finally in my HTML I have the following

```
    ...
    <div class="row">
        {{> posts}}
    </div>
    ...
    <template name="posts">
      <div class="span12">
      {{#each entry}}
        {{author}}
        {{date}}
        {{title}}
        {{headerHTML}}
        {{bodyHTML}}
      {{/each}}
      </div>
    </template>
```

When I have the app running the sections specified by {{headerHTML}} and {{bodyHTML}} return the literal string.  So you see the tags in the text.  What I want is for the string to be treated as HTML and displayed as such.  So some text will be bolded, I could have links, etc...  Any wisdom someone can throw my way?

I've tried putting the handlebars in various HTML tags (like `<p>{{bodyHML}}</p>`) with no luck.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use three brackets `{{{ }}}` to tell meteor not to escape your html strings.

```
 {{{headerHTML}}}
 {{{bodyHTML}}}
```

Comment: That was GLORIOUS!