# How to return html element from helper?

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-helper

I need to add html element form helper. Is there a way?

**Template:**

```
<template name="Index">
 <div class="title"> {{title}} </div>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
Template.Index.helpers({
  title: function(){
    var testvariable = "Hello <b>World</b>";
    return testvariable;
  }
})
```

**Note:** The below method will work fine. But in my case the title string is dynamic content.

```
<div class="title"> Hello <b>{{title}}</b> </div>
var testvariable = "World";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor.js, MongoDB retreiving HTML for use in Template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16565054/meteor-js-mongodb-retreiving-html-for-use-in-template)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use triple braces like this:

```
{{{ title }}}
```

Check [the docs](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md) for more infos.