# Server Side Rendering HTML text (write with HTML tags in DB) as effectively html in an email

Tags: meteor

#### On one hand

I've a field `will` in a collection, where user can save html text (through a WYSIWYG editor): it works fine and users can write/save some strings like this `it's<strong>bold</strong> and sometimes <i>italic</i>.` Nothing crazy..

#### On a second hand

When a user send this field `will` by email (as part of `emailData`), rendered with `meteorhacks:ssr` in an html template, the field show up as `it's<strong>bold</strong> and sometimes <i>italic</i>.` with HTML tags as normal text.

So, anyone know the trick to render in the html email's body: 'it's **bold** and sometimes *italic*.'? Thanks.

---

My code is very complicated, lot of `const` and succession of functions, but except of html rendering, it works fine and is finally structured like this:

```
SSR.compileTemplate('htmlEmail', Assets.getText('replycontact.html'));

var emailData = {
  message: `${message}`,
  will: `${will}`,
  origincontactdate: `${origincontactdate}`,
  contactname: `${contactname}`,
};
        
//send the mail
Email.send({
  to: to,
  from: from,
  subject: subject,
  html: SSR.render('htmlEmail', emailData),
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that Meteor was escaping the HTML string.

Therefore, the solution is to use 3 brackets `{{{ }}}` instead of 2  - here for the `emailData` in the html template : instead of `{{will}}`, use `{{{will}}}`.

The code above in the question remain as it.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16565529/7281870

Answer (score 0):

Your data is most likely being saved as HTML encoded in the database, eg

```
<b>
```

is saved as

```
&lt;b&gt;
```

If so, you simply need to unencode it using the Javascript decodeURI() function, which you can read more about here:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp

So your code will look like this:

```
var emailData = {
  message: `${message}`,
  will: decodeURI(${will}),
  origincontactdate: `${origincontactdate}`,
  contactname: `${contactname}`,
};

//send the mail
Email.send({
  to: to,
  from: from,
  subject: subject,
  html: SSR.render('htmlEmail', emailData),
});
```

Comment: Actually, `<b>` is really saved as `<b>`, not `&lt;b&gt;`: so `decodeURI()` sadly won't work..